# Why my json is not loading if I have all lines delimited?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to load a sample json:

```
{
  "bot_token": "##############################",
  "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS": "assets/firebase-adminsdk.json",
  "databaseURL": "https://########-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/",
  "storageBucket": "gs://##########.appspot.com",
  "owner_id": 0000000000,
  "admins": [0000000000]
}
```

Nothing special:

```
# Load configuration file
with open('assets/config.json', 'r') as f:
    config = json.load(f)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Exception has occurred: JSONDecodeError
Expecting ',' delimiter: line 6 column 16 (char 251)
  File "D:\SingleStoreBot\bot_init.py", line 58, in <module>
    config = json.load(f)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 6 column 16 (char 251)
```

I see all lines delimited so where is the error?

Comment: Looking at line 6 column 16 provides a pretty substantial hint.

Comment: Did you create this JSON yourself, or did you receive it from someone else? It's not valid JSON, as the integer part of a number (aside from 0 itself) cannot start with a zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers should be like this:

```
{
  "bot_token": "##############################",
  "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS": "assets/firebase-adminsdk.json",
  "databaseURL": "https://########-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/",
  "storageBucket": "gs://##########.appspot.com",
  "owner_id": 0,
  "admins": [0]
}
```

Comment: While true, it appears some JSON parsers (notably `jq`) accept numbers that start with a 0, despite what the JSON standard itself says.

Comment: (Maybe `jq` is the outlier, and such malformed JSON is not a widespread issue.)

Comment: Here's the standard: https://www.json.org/img/number.png if the first digit is 0 then only fraction or exponent follows